# How to generate fast, estimated statistics for a large quantity of rows with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

Imagine two tables:

foo

- foo_group_id (Foreign Key)
- created (timestamp)
- time (interval)

foo_group

- id
- name

There are hundreds of thousands of foo_groups and each group has millions of foo's. I'd like to calculate common statistics such as average, median, various percentile. We can assume this is time series data where foo.created always increases when new rows are inserted.

| Name | Avg | Median |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 156ms | 120ms |
| Second | 34ms | 30ms |

I need to sort and filter them. Running the query with a simple AVG function would get very slow. What are some ways to speed this up? Estimation would be fine. A constraint is that I would like to use only open source tools.

I've considered so far:

- A window function that picks some rows at random - but I'm not sure how to implement the at random part. And picking the first 1000 would be a poor estimation. Ideally, the estimate would need to scale in a way that lowers the sample size as the quantity increases to keep performant.
- Timescaledb's continuous aggregation sounds useful, but isn't part of their open source offering. I need my code to be open source and be redistributed.
- Save calculations at insert time, however this gets very complex with filtering. It's not sufficient to save only the total average for a group, as that would not apply to a date filter.

Comment: Store sum and count, pre-aggregated per day or so. Then it is easy to calculate averages.